# Screen going to sleep and then not coming back on

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, dual-boot

Recently set up a dual boot with windows 10 and linux mint 17.3 with windows 10 on an ssd and linux mint on a internal hdd. I have an ATI 7950 Raedon video card connected via miniDP to a Dell U2715H. When in linux, the screen will time out as normal after a given amount of time has passed, but then it will not come back on when I shake the mouse or press keys on the keyboard.

I usually have to resort to restarting the system (not ideal) or unplugging the cord on the monitor. However both of these solutions do not always work. Rebooting seems to stall at the linux mint boot image, so I have had to resort to booting into windows and then restarting and then booting back into linux mint and that seems to be working for now.

I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxepmtjmilQ this video to install the os. I use easyBCD for my boot options but it forces me to go to the metro version of os selection(even though I have it checked off). On this metro version, if I click windows 10 it will boot straight to it, but if I click linux mint option, it will reboot the system and then go to a grub selection screen.

I know this is a little wordy, and this may not be the right section, but if anyone has experienced this issue before and could provide some help, that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are running KDE or not, but I have a similar issue and I'm quite sure it's related to KDE.

This isn't a permanent fix but it will get you out of a pinch in the mean time.

What works for me is you switch TTY by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then back to your TTY where your X session is running.

I used to recycle the gfx monitor trigger by simply restarting the monitor. But this is quicker.